# Converting an update query with inner joins from vba to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

In converting to VB.Net with SQL Server, I need to convert an update query from vba code to SQL Server format.

VBA:

```
UPDATE tblEvtStructure 
INNER JOIN (tblEvtInput INNER JOIN tblPointsStructure ON 
    tblEvtInput.EvtPlaced = tblPointsStructure.Position) ON 
    tblEvtStructure.EvtStruct_Idx = tblEvtInput.EvtStructID
SET tblEvtInput.EvtPoints = [tblPointsStructure].[PointsAwarded]
WHERE tblEvtInput.EvtPlaced = [tblPointsStructure].[Position] 
      AND tblEvtInput.EvtPlacings = [tblPointsStructure].[InFinal] 
      AND tblEvtStructure.SectnID < 9 AND tblEvtInput.EvtSingle = 0
```

My attempt at SQL Server syntax so far - result is "0 rows affected":

```
UPDATE EI
SET    EI.EvtPoints = TPS.PointsAwarded
FROM   tblEvtInput AS EI 
INNER JOIN tblEvtStructure AS TES ON TES.EvtStruct_Idx = EI.EvtStructID 
INNER JOIN tblPointsStructure AS TPS ON TPS.Position = EI.EvtPlaced 
                                     AND EI.EvtPlaced = TPS.Position 
                                     AND EI.EvtPlacings = TPS.InFinal
WHERE (TES.SectnID < 9) AND (EI.EvtSingle = 0)
```

I need help trying to get to grips with this please

Comment: VBA (or VB.NET) doesn't know anything about SQL. If the VBA code worked against an SQL Server backend, there's no reason the exact same query wouldn't work if sent to SQL Server from a VB.NET front-end. Did the back-end change? If not, you're changing 4 quarters for a dollar. Oh I see - the backend was Access and you're changing it to SQL Server. Might be worth mentioning somewhere? VBA is irrelevant here - only the flavor of SQL is.

Comment: are you sure that query bring the desire rows. try run a SELECT instead to see you have any data matching those conditions.

Comment: The query comes from my access accdb database connected to a backend mdb I'm re-writing the whole thing in VB.Net using an sql server in the back so someone else can also process data besides myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good.  The only obvious problem is the qualified column name in `set` -- not allowed there.  So:

```
UPDATE EI
    SET EvtPoints = TPS.PointsAwarded
    FROM tblEvtInput EI INNER JOIN
         tblEvtStructure TES
         ON TES.EvtStruct_Idx = EI.EvtStructID INNER JOIN
         tblPointsStructure TPS
         ON TPS.Position = EI.EvtPlaced AND
            EI.EvtPlaced = TPS.Position AND
            EI.EvtPlacings = TPS.InFinal
    WHERE (TES.SectnID < 9) AND (EI.EvtSingle = 0);
```

I removed the `as`es for the table aliases, as a matter of my personal preference.

Comment: If problem was qualified column, wouldn't that generate an error? OP say updated 0 rows.